# Regex replacement match per match

Tags: c#, regex

i have a bit of a problem with code that should work but doesn't for some reason.
The idea is that i have two string and i need to replace some text in one with text from the other to fix some errors.
First, my code:

```
var rx2 = new Regex(@"<[^><]*>|<[^<]*(<[^>]*>)*[^>]*>");
MatchCollection matchesorig = rx2.Matches(or);
int c = 0;
if (matchesorig.Count > 0)
de = rx2.Replace(de, match =>
{
    var res = matchesorig[c].Value;
    c++;
    return res;
});
```

So i get a collection of matches from my original string (or) and then i go to the target string (de) and go match by match replacing with the match in the origibal string

i've tested in `RegExBuilder` and both have 24 matches, so why don't i get the result i want?

**EDIT:** as requested:

```
or = <bpt id="48"><size val="1400"></bpt><bpt id="49"><fill-sd val="<a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="616A71"/></a:solidFill>"></bpt>Number of vehicles in COUNTRY <ept id="49"></fill-sd></ept><ept id="48"></size></ept><bpt id="50"><size val="1600"></bpt><bpt id="51"><fill-sd val="<a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="00A76D"/></a:solidFill>"></bpt>X.XXX.XXX<ept id="51"></fill-sd></ept><ept id="50"></size></ept>
de = <bpt id="48"><size val="1400"></bpt><bpt id="49"><Encher-sd val = "<a:solidFill> <a:srgbClr val="616A71"/> </ a: solidFill>"></bpt>Número de veículos no país <ept id="49"></ Encher-sd></ept><ept id="48"></ Tamanho></ept><bpt id="50"><size val="1600"></bpt><bpt id="51"><Encher-sd val = "<a:solidFill> <a:srgbClr val="00A76D"/> </ a: solidFill>"></bpt>X.XXX.XXX<ept id="51"></ Encher-sd></ept><ept id="50"></ Tamanho></ept>
```

Exception:

```
The argumente specified was outsider the interval of valid values.
parameter Name: i
```

Exception thrown at line:

```
var res = matchesorig[c].Value;
```

With C = 24

**EDIT2:** As pointed out int the comments, the problem de string has a few inconsistences that break the regex:

```
< fill-sd val = "< <a:solidFill> a:srgbClr"/"616A71 = val > </a:solidFill>">
```

notice the `< <` and the `> </`. In the first, the < is out of place (it should be after the next >, and in the second there's a space not taken into account by the regex i am using. This makes de have 26 rather than 24 matches. Handling the space is trivial, but what about the < in the wrong place? i can't change that string as i get it from a internet service to wich i have no access (they have an issue that i only found now) so i need to deal with the string as is. ideas?

**EDIT3:** I came up with this solution (testing now)

```
<[^<>]*>|<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>)*[^<>]*>|<[^<>]*<[^<>]*<[^<>]*>\s{0,1}[^<>]*>\s{0,1}(<[^<>]*>\s{0,1})*[^<>]*>
```

Anyone see any problem/has a shorter version?

Comment: What are your strings? What results are you getting now?

Comment: The result i am getting is an execption in line var res = matchesorig[c].Value; trying to make a replacement when c=24 when there should only be matches from 0 to 23. I'll post the strings in a moment - will have to regenerate them and that takes a few minutes - sorry

Comment: It would be great if you can share some samples.

Comment: I see 26 matches in `de`...

Comment: @Vache: aaaaaaaaaaaah - you're right - i must have copied the wrong string when i checked in RegExBuilder. Good news is i found the problema - de adds a space within a big match that contains posible matches and my regEx doens't take that into consideration - thanks

Comment: Well that and < tags out of place :p how am i gonna fix that now? good question

Comment: Perhaps a solution with LINQToXML would be more appropriate than regex here...

Comment: @Vache except - the xml is broken here - wouldn't linqtoxml complain and not work? can you give me a working solution as an answer?

Comment: Yeah probably. I don't really know your needs, just mentioning that regex is rarely a good idea to work with XML.

Comment: @Vache - quite true - then again this isn't quite xml - although most rules apply - and i'm getting it broken from the service - so any option that parses XML is likely to fail. Just as my new attempt at a regex did :( - back to the drawing board... tomorrow

Comment: oops - fixed the de value - sorry ppl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing it came down to the following regex:

```
<[^<>]*>|<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>\s{0,1})*[^<>]*>
```

thanks go to @Vache for pointing out i was testing the wrong string  -  duuhh